# Significado da sintaxe do append

Tags: javascript, jquery, sintaxe

```
$("#add_city_btn2").click(function() {
    var city = $("#add_city2").val();
    $("#cities2").append($("<option>", { text: city, selected: "selected"})).change();
    $("#add_city2").val('');
    return false;
});
```

o que significa a linha abaixo desse código? não entendi principalmente a parte entre chaves.

```
 $("#cities2").append($("<option>", { text: city, selected: "selected"})).change();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É criado uma option nova com o texto(descrição), que está contido na variável `city` e é marcado como `selected` opção selecionada.

```
{ text: city, selected: "selected"}
```

Answer (score 11):

Essa linha faz 4 coisas:

#### #1: seleciona o elemento com ID `cities2`

Esta é a funcionalidade básica do jQuery, selecionar elementos do DOM, meste caso provavelmente `<select id="cities2">`. O equivalente em JavaScript nativo seria

```
document.getElementById('cities2');
```

#### #2: cria um novo elemento `option`

`$("<option>", { text: city, selected: "selected"})` cria um novo elemento que fica no HTML com este aspeto:

```
<option selected="selected"><o valor da variavel city></option>
```

#### #3: adiciona-o no select com `.append()`

Aqui o jQuery insere este novo elemento no final dos descendentes do `<select>`. O equivalente nativo é `.appendChild()`.

#### #4: dispara um evento `change`

Este código anterior (em #1, #2 e #3) muda a opção selecionada no select. Porém como isto é feito programáticamente e não por interação do utilizador é preciso disparar o evento `change` para outras partes do código que estejam à espera de correr quando o select fôr mudado serem acionados.